# Share data between subprocesses ran by supervisord

Tags: python, multiprocessing, supervisord

I have python script, which must do an action given number of times. I use supervisord to run multiple instances of this script. Each script has code like follow:

```
    count = 0
    while count != MAX_COUNT:
        try:
            perform_action()
            count += 1
        except Exception, e:
            print 'Error happened...'
            print e
```

So, for example, I run 10 processes and MAX_COUNT=1000. In this case each script will do `perform_acion()` 1000 times. But I need 1000 times at all. So, I need to share somehow `count` of perform_action() executions between all supervisord subprocesses.

How can I do it?

I think about using redis\memcached\sqlite - but maybe here is another solution?

Answer (score 0):

variable 'count' is initialized to 0 in beginning of each script, you should store count to a shared place and access it exclusively by each process.

Comment: So, you think - that using simple file (for example) will be good idea?

Comment: I prefer shared memory. or maybe, using threading is easier to modify a shared variable for this scenario than multi process.